# Angular serialize Markdown using RegEx

Tags: angular, regex, markdown

I have a markdown file in Angular structured similar to this:

```
## Headline ##

### 1. Sub-headline ###
Lorem ipsum

### 2. Sub-headline ###
Lorem Ipsum

## Heading 2 ##

### 1. Sub-headline ###
Lorem ipsum
```

and would like to read the file and convert it to objects like this:

```
{
 heading1: 'Headline',
 heading2: [
  {
   title: '1. Sub-headline',
   text: 'Lorem ipsum
  },
  {
   title: '2. Sub-headline',
   text: 'Lorem ipsum
  }
 ]
},
...
```

and so on...
I read the file with a HttpClient.get and want to filter the text response for the headings and appendent text, so I tried several RegEx executions like this:

```
this.http.get('path/to/file.md',{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => {
 const regEx = new RegEx('((\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)#{2} (.*) #{2})|(#{3} (.*)(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)(.*|(.*(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n))*)(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n){2})','g');

 let match;

 while((match = regEx.exec(res)) !== null) {
  console.log(match);
 }
});
```

and several other regEx but nothing seems to work.. the idea is to, at first, break it down to heading1 and corresponding content, and then break those blocks down further..

Comment: So I managed to filter out heading1s, heading2s etc stand alone, but the problem is that then I don't know the corresponding heading one level higher, and I fail to firstly break it into big chunks with only one heading1 and corresponding content.. if it is clear what I mean..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up splitting the text of the md file by '\n' so I got an array with all lines and could then iterate through it, check for the number of '#' in each line and process it that way.